# Flutter firebase_messaging on receiving message when app is closed

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with firebase_messaging to receive some messages on my app. All works well when I receive a push and the app is opened or in the background, but when I close the app on my android device and receive a message, I receive a message and the app crashes: "AppName keeps stopping. App info / Close app"

Follow below some code:

page.dart code to firebase_messaging

```
final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
StreamSubscription iosSubscription;

initNotification() {
  iosSubscription = _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((data) {
    print('data: $data')
  });

  _fcm.getToken().then(_tokenRefresh, onError: _tokenRefreshFailure);

  _fcm.configure(
     onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onMessage: $message");
     },
     onBackgroundMessage: fcmBackgroundMessageHandler,
     onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onLaunch: $message");
     },
     onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onResume: $message");
     }
    },
  );
}
void _tokenRefresh(String newToken) async {
 print("New FCM Token $newToken");
}

void _tokenRefreshFailure(error) {
 print("FCM token refresh failed with error $error");
}
void _refreshToken() {
 _fcm.getToken().then(_tokenRefresh, onError: _tokenRefreshFailure);
}
```

app build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.4'
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Do you know what do I need to do to solve this issue?

Is there any way to debug it because when I close the app on an android device obviously I loose my debug.

Comment: App crashed once app exit?

Comment: App crashes on push notification click, trying to open the app.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: "AppName keeps stopping. App info / Close app". I don't know how to send the report to my email to get more details.